# Unable to see VIEWS in SageMaker UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

We have a connection from SageMaker to Snowflake, and need to see **views** (as opposed to tables) listed when using Data Wrangler. Is there a reason that views are not shown in the data listing of Data Wrangler?

We have checked security settings and access. These are not materialized views.

Comment: Views may not be visible in the UI, you can use them in the SELECT query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Data Wrangler does not support browsing Views in the UI but you can still query them with SELECT.